# GAE Cloud Datastore: Get most frequently read models

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to get the list of models in decreasing order of most frequently read models. This is what I have tried so far.This client query set gives the details of models and their attributes/properties, with these model related details : **Entity count**, **Built-in index count**, **Built-in index size**, **Data size**, **Composite index size**, **Composite index count**. But there is no detail about read frequencies

```
from google.cloud import datastore
import math

def run_quickstart():
    # [START datastore_quickstart]
    # Imports the Google Cloud client library

    client = datastore.Client()
    query = client.query(kind='__Stat_Kind__')
    detail_list = []
    items = list(query.fetch())
    for results in items:
        results = results.viewitems()
        detail_list.append(results)

    print detail_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_quickstart()
```

Does GAE Cloud Datastore provide any such information of database read frequencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, no datastore read frequency stats are being (presently at least) maintained. Check the [Datastore Statistics](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/stats) article to see the complete list of stats available.

A similar question was posted not long ago for the write stats: [GAE Cloud Datastore: Get most frequently written models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50303675/gae-cloud-datastore-get-most-frequently-written-models). Similarly to that answer you could build a scheme to keep read stats yourself. You might find the [PreGet](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/callbacks#PreGet) hook (and/or its friends) handy.

For my app I built a datastore access tracking scheme which could be used to gather such stats as well (but it only covers direct entity lookups, not those read through query results). See [Are ndb cached read ops still counted as datastore read ops for billing purposes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50284922/are-ndb-cached-read-ops-still-counted-as-datastore-read-ops-for-billing-purposes/50403081#50403081)

Comment: Thank you for provide me such a good information. It really help full to me.